# Partial refresh on fields onchange event is not working

Tags: xpages

I am getting Partial refresh problem in XPages can any one help me on this.

I have two fields called txtCategory and txtPolicy, I am doing a lookup in a field called txtClause based on these two fields, I have a view called vwKeyword which has first column field mapping is like: "txtCategory~txtPolicy"

At first time the fields are getting populated properly, if I change the fields txtCategory and or txtPolicy the third field txtClause is not refreshing

evevt-OnChange of txtCategory I am partially refreshing txtPolicy
evevt-OnChange of txtPolicy I am partially refreshing txtClause

Thanks in advance,
JB
This is my code on the field:txtClause

```
var val1 =  getComponent("txtCategory").getValue();
var val2 =  getComponent("txtPolicy").getValue();
var key  =  val1+"~"+val2;
@DbLookup(@DbName(),"vwKeyword",key,2);
```

Comment: Please include all of the code for the 3 fields. It sounds like you need to change the onChange event for txtCategory and for txtPolicy to partially refresh txtClause (txtCategory should not refresh txtPolicy as txtClause will then remain unchanged).

Answer (score 0):

There are two scenarios as follows,

1. First check the onchange event, whether this is working or not. put try catch for catching the Error.
2. Second, Check all your field name is correct. It may be the careless mistake.